# How do I create an object in another class when the parameter is out of scope?

Tags: java, object, maze

I have three classes: `Mazesolver`, `Hexagon`, and `Maze`. When I try to create a `Hexagon` object in the `Mazesolver` class an error occurs. Can anyone please help me with this problem? Also, what does it mean to obtain a reference to the Start `Hexagon` in the maze?

```
public class Hexagon extends HexComponent
{
    // constants
    private static final Color WALL_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color START_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    private static final Color END_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final Color UNVISITED_COLOR = Color.CYAN;
    private static final Color PROCESSED_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color PUSHED_COLOR = Color.MAGENTA;
    private static final Color END_PROCESSED_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color START_PROCESSED_COLOR = Color.PINK;

    //enum to represent available hexagon types
    public static enum HexType{WALL, START, END, UNVISITED, PROCESSED, PUSHED,       END_PROCESSED, START_PROCESSED};

    // Attributes   
    private HexType type;    // Stores the type of Hexagon this currently is  
    private boolean isStart;  // Is this the start?
    private boolean isEnd;    // Is this the end?
    private Hexagon[] neighbors; // Stores the hexagons which surround this one  on each of 6 sides

    /**
     * Create a Hexagon tile of the specified type 
     * @param t the HexType to create
     */
    public Hexagon(HexType t) {
        this.type = t;
        this.isStart = t == HexType.START;
        this.isEnd = t == HexType.END;

        //set the initial color based on the initial type
        this.setColor(this.type);
        //allocate space for the neighbor array
        this.neighbors = new Hexagon[6];
    }
```

How do I create a object of Hexagon in MazeSolver?

```
public class MazeSolver 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Maze Provided");
            }
            String maze0 = args[0];
            private ArrayStack<String> steps;
            Hexagon Start = new Hexagon(t);  //error
        }
```

Comment: Your `ArrayStack` instance `steps` has an illegal modifier. You can't use `private` on a locally-scoped variable within a method. Additionally, you haven't included any details on what kind of error you're seeing. Please add those details to your post. As is, it's impossible to say which errors are due to a bad copy/paste vs. actual issues.

Answer (score 3):

I am no coding Guru but it may be because the only `Hexagon` constructor requires you to pass a `HexType` value. I may be wrong but what I think the problem is, is that you are passing `t` into your Hexagon constructor when `t` is not a `HexType` value. You need to pass one of these to your Hexagon constructor: `HexType.WALL, HexType.START, HexType.END, HexType.UNVISITED, HexType.PROCESSED, HexType.PUSHED, HexType.END_PROCESSED, HexType.START_PROCESSED`.

EDIT: So yea I think it is safe to say you just have to pass `HexType.VALUE` to your Hexagon constructor, VALUE being any value of your HexType enum class.

I am new to StackOverFlow, please let me know if I am wrong so I can delete my answer or at least correct it.

Comment: Yes, @LeonelRamos i am sure that's the problem.

Comment: @TedLaw Could you also post StackTrace of your error.

Comment: When I change T to START , it says START cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: The larger issue you didnt address is that OP passes an undefined variable into the constructor. OP needs either `new Hexagon(HexType.START)` or `HexType t = HexType.START; Hexagon start = new Hexagon(t);`

Comment: @Ted Law, try passing HexType.START because START does not mean anything therefore it cannot be resolved to a to a variable, you might as well be passing in any random word, But having HexType. first lets it know that START is a type in HexType; again i may be wrong but you should try it.

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble whoops forgot enum is a class so you are correct. You must pass a new instance of it so (new HexType(HexType.START) should work, I think.

Comment: @LeonelRamos i actually edited that bc i forgot it was an enum as well. Your way was better, more semantically appropriate to me.

Comment: "You must pass a new instance of it so (new HexType(HexType.START) should work, I think" Unnecessary - passing `HexType.START` is just enough. Attempting to create another `HexType` instance for the same value may result in a compilation error.

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble, damn yea I guess I was right the first time around, i'll edit my post again, sorry, I have not worked with enums in a while and was too lazy to look up how they work.

Comment: @LeonelRamos   I changed my code to                 Hexagon Start = HexType.START ;  but it is still a red line under the HexType it also says cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @TedLaw you have to pass it as a parameter because  `Hexagon Start = HexType.START` this like saying `String numAsString = 123` when you should be passing `123` to a constructor of the method `String.valueOf()`, So what you should be doing is `Hexagon start = new Haxagon(HexType.START)`. You see? Passing HexType.START as a parameter not trying to make Hexagon = HexType

Answer (score 0):

```
        Hexagon Start = new Hexagon(t);  //error
```

Into above line everything is correct except :

1) it may be **t** is not define, firstly define **t** as Hexagon before using it.

2) it may be you have defined **t** somewhere into code but that must be Hexagon, change its type to Hexagon.

3) if you have done correctly above both point then you have to import Hexagon class into MazeSolver. lke :

```
import <Package>.HEXAGON;
public class MazeSolver 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Maze Provided");
            }
            String maze0 = args[0];
            private ArrayStack<String> steps;
            HexType t;   // Change Here 
            Hexagon Start = new Hexagon(t);  // No Error
```

Comment: When I change T to HEX

Comment: When I change T to HEXTYPE . it says cannot be resolved to a variable.What should I do now

Comment: @TedLaw you know what is HexType, Please share about HexType

Comment: public static enum HexType{WALL, START, END, UNVISITED, PROCESSED, PUSHED, END_PROCESSED, START_PROCESSED};    it is in the HEXAGON class

Comment: @TedLaw So you have to follow 3(third) step see edited answer